# Cannot reference selected option's index

Tags: jquery, html

I want to get the selected option's index inside the onchange of a multiple select element :

```
<select id="secta_code" name="secta_code[]" multiple="multiple" size="10" onchange="refreshProduits($(this option:selected).index());">
</select>

function refreshProduits(idx) {
    alert("zzzzzzzzzz");
}
```

But the alert does not appear ! What is wrong ?

Comment: Look at your JavaScript console. You will see an error message.

Comment: Ok, i saw. Why your select does not have any option inside?

Comment: There is an error saying : uncaught syntaxerror , unexpected identifier

Comment: The select's options are added when I click a button : `$('#btnOneSecteur').click(function() {
  var selected = $("#secteurs option:selected").val();
  var selOptionLen = $('#secta_code option[value="'+ selected +'"]').length;
  if (!selOptionLen) {
   var clone = $('#secteurs option:selected').clone();
   clone.appendTo('#secta_code');
  }
 });`

Comment: for me, this `multiple` attribute isn't working. i can only select one option at a time. 0.o BTW, if you can select multiple options at a time, then how can you get the `index` of selected element, since there will be many..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the mistake might have simply been the missing quotes,

i.e

```
refreshProduits($(this option:selected).index());
```

should have been, which is a shorthand for $(this).find(query)

```
refreshProduits($(this, "option:selected").index());
```

I'd recommend binding using .on() rather than inline JavaScript, and also .index() won't work correctly for multiple select options, you'll need to use .val() which will give you a list of selected values.

```
$("#secta_code").on('change', function() {
    var values = $(this, 'option:selected').val();
    alert("zzzzzzzzzz " + values);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you should do this:

```
refreshProduits($(this).find('option:selected').index());
```

You're syntax was wrong in jQuery part. And you should not be using inline-js when you load jQuery.
You can use `children()` too if its immediate children.

Comment: Why should I use find ?

Comment: @pheromix: Use `find` if the descendant elements might be more than one level down.  In this case that could happen if you have `optgroup` elements.  If the target elements will only ever be one level down, use `children`.

Comment: But why is writing `$('checkbox:selected')` correct then ?

Comment: @pheromix it is correct as it is a selector. You were trying to include `this` and the selector and for doing that you need some other overload

Comment: @pheromix: Writing any syntactically valid selector is "correct" in that it will at least execute.  Whether or not it finds the elements you're targeting is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

This is invalid syntax:

```
$(this option:selected)
```

The jQuery selector isn't going to be able to guess what you mean, you have to provide it with valid syntax.  Maybe you meant something more like this?:

```
$(this).children("option:selected")
```

Or possibly:

```
$(this).find("option:selected")
```

If you group your options.

Comment: I opted for Adam's answer and it worked ! thankx Adam !

Comment: @pheromix: Also syntactically correct.  Be aware that they do somewhat different things.  Make sure your code "works" because you know what it's doing, rather than "works" by coincidence alone.  It'll be a lot easier to debug future problems that way :)